# Setting cors headers in Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In my Azure function, I try to set cors headers:

```
var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new ObjectContent<List<RecordEntity>>(data, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/json");

response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

return response;
```

However, none of these headers get to the client in the http response, they are stripped from the response.

I suppose there is some other way of setting the cors headers, but cannot find how it works.

Comment: There are some issues around that. Maybe this https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/620 and this can help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/12/azure-functions-access-control-allow-credentials-with-cors/

Comment: I tried setting CORS in 'Storage account' in Azure portal for Table service, but still the headers is not sent to the client.

Comment: Maybe your function is only listening to GET requests while CORS pre-flight requests come as OPTIONS requests? You can also enable CORS on the Function App itself to have it handle the OPTIONS requests.

Comment: I finally found the CORS setting under Function App -> Platform Features. What helped was to delete all allowed origins from the list (as described in the link above https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/12/azure-functions-access-control-allow-credentials-with-cors/, thanks), then finally my own cors headers were sent to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CORS setting in the Azure portal is under Function App -> Platform Features.

What helped was to delete all Allowed origins from the list (as described in the link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/12/azure-functions-access-control-allow-credentials-with-cors/).

When the list of Allowed origins is empty, then finally the manually set cors headers are sent from Azure function in the http response to the client and are not stripped.

Comment: CORS now has its own setting page. You'll find it on Function App home screen, API > CORS. Just remove the default entry, add `*`, hit 'Save' and you are done.

Emptying the list and adding headers manually didn't work for me.

Comment: * doesn`t work for me, and I`m beyond confused as to what the steps should be.

Comment: I have removed all entries and added the `*`. I am not sure why it is still not working but I don't see the access control header in the response :(