# Javascript call of Azure Function with AD authentification from SharePoint Online

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

I have one big problem with call of azure function. My azure function work perfectly when authentication is OFF. In SharePoint online I have this JS code:

```
var serviceURL = "https://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?name=test";

$.ajax({
    url: serviceURL,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success: " + data);
    },
    error: function (ex) {
        alert("Failure getting user token");
    }
});
```

Ok so this is working. But When I setup Active Directory Authentication on mu Azure Function and change my code to this:

```
    var serviceURL = "https://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?name=test";

$.ajax({
    url: serviceURL,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "'application/json;odata=verbose'",
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "crossDomain": "true",
        "credentials": "include",
        "Access-Control-Allow-credentials": "true"
    },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success: " + data);
    },
    error: function (ex) {
        alert("Failure getting user token");
    }
});
```

I get this error

> SEC7122: [CORS] The origin 'https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com' made a request using credentials mode 'include' and did not find an Access-Control-Allow-credentials response header with a value of 'true' for cross-origin  resource at 'https://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?name=test'.

My azure function look like this

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // parse query parameter
        string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
            .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
            .Value;

        if (name == null)
        {
            // Get request body
            dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
            name = data?.name;
        }

        return name == null
            ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
            : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name);
    }
```

I have allowed in CORS settings my sharepoint domain so there is everything ok... I have tested everything but nothing helps me with this problem...Same problem...In my azure function I have tested to setup express or advanced management mode for AD authentification but nothing helsp....Thank you for your help.

Comment: Likely related to https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/620, see this issue too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53321897/setting-cors-headers-in-azure-function

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help. The problem is if I remove my domain from cors list the problem is little different: SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'xxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com' did not find 'xxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin resource at 'xxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?name=test

Comment: If I call my function directly from web browser then I must login and after that everything works...But from javascript there still same error.

Comment: if you remove all cors from the portal, you have to send the header in the response manually